# What does it mean(physically) when a material has high permittivity?

Tags: electric-fields, polarization, physical-constants

I read somewhere that the idea of permittivity is that it tells us about how much a material gets polarized when an electric field passes through it.
So for example if the permittivity is 31, does it mean that 30(as in, 31-1) parts of the Electric field is used to polarize it, and the other 1 part passes through it?